# How to pay payment of particular rows of the gridview emoloyee salary when click on pay button my gridview code is mentioned below

Tags: asp.net

```
<div>
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>
              <asp:Label runat="server" text="Search"></asp:Label>
          </td>
          <td>
              <asp:TextBox runat="Server" placeholder="Enter EmpId" id="txtSearch">
              </asp:TextBox>
          </td>
          <td>
              <asp:Button ID="btnGo" runat="server" Text="Go" onclick="btnGo_Click"/>
          </td>
          <td>  
             <asp:Button ID="btnShowAll" runat="server" Text="ShowAll" 
                    onclick="btnShowAll_Click" />
          </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
       <Columns>
          <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="EmpId" DataField="EmpId"/>
          <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Employee Name" DataField="EmpName"/>
          <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Designation" DataField="EmpDesgn"/>
          <asp:BoundField  HeaderText="Salary" DataField="Sal"/>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Salary Status">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Button runat="Server" id="btnPay" text="Pay" CommandName="Pay"
                  Visible='<%#Eval("Status").Equals("Paid")?false:true %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>        
       </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

I want to pay the salary of unpaid employees on clicking the pay button as pay button is showing only for unpaid salaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using OnRowCommand event. Add the event handler to the gridview

```
OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
```

Bind the command argument to your button

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Salary Status">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Button runat="Server" id="btnPay" text="Pay" CommandName="Pay"
              Visible='<%#Eval("Status").Equals("Paid")?false:true %>' 
              CommandArgument = '<%#Eval("EmpId")%>'
              />
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Then in the RowCommand event you can catch the EmpId from the command argument, pay the salary and rebind the grid view

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName=="Pay")
    {
        // get the command argument.
        string empId = e.CommandArgument as string;
        //you code here to pay the salary
        //ReBind Gridview to refresh
    }
}
```